# Clean dirty data

Tags: matlab, stata

I have three variables (ID, Name and City) and need to `generate` a new variable flag.

There are something wrong with the observations. I need to find the wrong observations and create the flag.  The variable flag indicates which column contains the wrong observation.

Suppose just one bad observation at most in each row.

Given dirty data!!!!!

```
|ID      |Name             |City 
|1       |IBM              |D    
|1       |IBM              |D    
|2       |IBM              |D    
|3       |Google           |F    
|3       |Microsoft        |F    
|3       |Google           |F    
|8       |Microsoft        |A    
|8       |Microsoft        |B    
|8       |Microsoft        |A
```

Result

```
|ID      |Name             |City |flag
|1       |IBM              |D    |0
|1       |IBM              |D    |0
|2       |IBM              |D    |1
|3       |Google           |F    |0
|3       |Microsoft        |F    |2
|3       |Google           |F    |0
|8       |Microsoft        |A    |0
|8       |Microsoft        |B    |3
|8       |Microsoft        |A    |0
```

Comment: Could you understand the question? @NickCox

Comment: OK, thank you very much.

Comment: You need a reference first. You would need a separate table which would give the `unique ID` of each `company` ... then you could do simple comparisons and find your bad observations.

Comment: It's a dirty data. There is no unique ID. I just suppose one bad observation at most in each row.

Comment: Still don't know what you are asking exactly. Do you find it difficult to identify dirty data or attach a flag to each data?

Comment: It's difficult to identify dirty data

Comment: Are your data already sorted in the order of your example? Are they always grouped into 3s as in your example?

Comment: @EricHB it is sorted by ID and they are grouped into 3s.

Comment: Okay, are the IDs guaranteed to be in ascending order, i.e. would it be possible for your thrid observation of ID (the "wrong" observation) to be 9 instead of 2?

Comment: It is sorted by IDs in ascending order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is based on Eric's answer.

```
clear all
input float ID str9 Name str1 City
1 "IBM"       "D"
1 "IBM"       "D"
2 "IBM"       "D"
3 "Google"    "F"
3 "Microsoft" "F"
3 "Google"    "F"
8 "Microsoft" "A"
8 "Microsoft" "B"
8 "Microsoft" "A"
end

encode Name, gen(Name_n)
encode City, gen(City_n)

// get dummy variable for 
duplicates tag ID Name, gen(col_12)
duplicates tag ID City, gen(col_13)
duplicates tag Name City, gen(col_23)
duplicates tag ID Name City, gen(col_123)

// generate the flag
gen flag = 0
replace flag = 1 if col_123 == 0 & col_23 ~= 0
replace flag = 2 if col_123 == 0 & col_13 ~= 0
replace flag = 3 if col_123 == 0 & col_12 ~= 0

drop Name_n City_n col_*
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is an answer in Stata that rests on many assumptions that you pointed out in the comments but not the initial quesiton:

```
clear all
input float ID str9 Name str1 City
1 "IBM"       "D"
1 "IBM"       "D"
2 "IBM"       "D"
3 "Google"    "F"
3 "Microsoft" "F"
3 "Google"    "F"
8 "Microsoft" "A"
8 "Microsoft" "B"
8 "Microsoft" "A"
end

// get dummy variable for 
duplicates tag, gen(right)

gen flag = 0

encode Name, gen(Name_n)
encode City, gen(City_n)

qui sum
forvalues start = 1(3)`r(N)' {
    local end = `start'+2

    // check if ID is all same
    qui sum ID in `start'/`end'
    if `r(sd)' != 0 {
        replace flag = 1 in `start'/`end' if right == 0
        continue
    }

    // check if name is all same
    qui sum Name_n in `start'/`end'
    if `r(sd)' != 0 {
        replace flag = 2 in `start'/`end' if right == 0
        continue
    }

    // chech if city is all same
    qui sum City_n in `start'/`end'
    if `r(sd)' != 0 {
        replace flag = 3 in `start'/`end' if right == 0
        continue
    }
}

drop right Name_n City_n
```

The intuition is that because they are grouped in 3s, two are always right, there is only one issue per group of 3, and they are sorted by ID which can be wrong but not greater than the next greatest right ID we can first check for duplicates, if there is a duplicate observation then that observation is right.

Next, (in the forvalues loop) we go through each group of three to see which of the variables has the wrong value, when we find it, we replace flag with the appropriate number.